# Left click doesn't work while typing. Synaptics touchpad driver

Tags: windows-10, touchpad, regedit, synaptics-touchpad

I cannot use my left click while pressing any key of my keyboard.

I previously couldn't use the touchpad while pressing any key, but I fixed this by changing some Regedit values for Synaptics.

I searched everywhere, literally, I couldn't find anything. I don't have Synaptics control panel so I cannot disable Palmcheck or any feature that is causing this.

I'm looking for the regedit value(s) that I need to change to disable this feature.

Answer (score 1):

In the Registry Editor, Go to Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\PrecisionTouchPad and set AAP Threshold to 0. Reset and you should be able to click while typing again.

But please, PLEASE, what did you change to let you use the trackpad while typing?

Answer (score 0):

> I'm looking for the regedit value(s) that I need to change to disable this feature.

Why do you do that? Who said to change registry entries would solve the problem? This is not a reason to modify registry entries. In fact, *only* experienced users should touch the Registry. Else you could harm the whole operation system.

A driver reinstallation or upgrade shall solve the problem.

If not, I would tend to search the issue on the hardware and not the software.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

What https://superuser.com/users/759418/lane said is the correct answer. Here it is as a picture for people needing more encouragement.